# Leaflet JS: Hiding API key of map tile provider

Tags: leaflet, mapquest, cloudmade

I know this may come off as a very noob question.

I'm using Leaflet JS for mapping purposes in my application. For the mapping tile providers, I setup both MapQuest and Cloudmade.
Both of them have a format similar to

```
tileserver.com/SOME_PARAMS/API_KEY/TILE_NUMBERS
```

to fetch the appropriate tiles to show in the map container.

What I'm confused is how can I keep the tiling javascript API key hidden from end users?

Comment: See Justin's answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611072/how-to-secure-the-javascript-api-access-token

Answer (score 0):

Generally this isn't possible: even if you were to write some JavaScript to obfuscate that value, anyone could just right-click on a tile and see the API key in its URL.