# How to hide Mapbox Access Token

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-marker

I'm using Mapbox for maps, and the access token is public where people visit the website can easily copy. Is there a way to hide this access token or limit access to only my website? It seems other people are using my access code to do Python Requests for geocodes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    L.marker([40.7127837, -74.0059413]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(mymap)
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611072/how-to-secure-the-javascript-api-access-token

Comment: [This guide](https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-to-use-mapbox-securely/) on how to use Mapbox securely may be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You could add URL restrictions to your access token:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/account/tokens/#domain-restrictions

Or you could hide your token with a method like this:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-hide-your-API-customer-key-token-when-youre-pushing-code-to-Github

I hope that's helpful!